# After split(), list encountered IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a datafile and get the data.

My Python code:

```
f = open('datafile', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    print line

    dataList = line.split('-')

    print dataList
    print len(dataList)
    print dataList[0]

    # print dataList[1] # IndexError: list index out of range
    # print dataList[2] # IndexError: list index out of range
    # print dataList[3] # IndexError: list index out of range
```

For example, taking one line in that file, the code has following output:

```
0A-02-01-04
['0A', '02', '01', '02']
4
0A
```

But accessing other member data gives out of range error

Comment: Change your `list.split` to `dataList = line.split('-')`

Comment: the original python is dataList = line.split('-'), I made a mistake on posting the question

Comment: `s = '0A-02-01-04'; l = s.split('-'); print(l[1])` printing `02` so it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error when your line doesn't have enough "parts", or if the line is empty.

`.split('-')` will return a list with one item, if your line is empty:

```
>>> ''.split('-')
['']
```

Start by filtering out blank lines, or - if you know that the data will always have 4 parts, check the length of the resulting list:

```
if len(dataList) == 4:
    # do stuff here
else:
    # blank line, or invalid data, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access other data members because line you are splitting may not contain `-` in itself, so when you applying `split` to line in returns list with one item and that item equals to `line`.

```
line = '312312'
print line.split('-')
# ['312312']
```

So to access data by index check whether data has such count of elements with calling `len(data)` method.

```
if len(data) > index: print(data[index])
```

Comment: The original python file is using "line.split('-')". I made a mistake on typing the question.